# UICollectionView: reloadData() cause cell to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionView with a custom layout, so far I only have one `UICollectionReusableView`. At first everything works fine:

1. `prepareLayout()` is called that fills up the cache,
2. `collectionViewContentSize()` is called and returns the right cententSize and
3. `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect()` is called and return the right attributes.

This causes the collectionView's `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`-method to be called, after which the view becomes visible.

Later, when I press a button, the size of the reuseable view changes, and `collectionView.reloadData()` is called. This causes the 3 above mentioned methods to be called again, and they still returns the right values with new sizes, but this time it doesn't trigger `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, and the collectionView gets empty.

**Why isn't `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` called?**

---

Debug example:

The return of `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` the first time the collection view is layed out (i.e. when it works)

```
layout attributes: [<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fa5005dc970> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 0; 414 1106); ]
```

The return of `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` the second time the collection view is layed out (i.e. when it doens't works)

```
layout attributes: [<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fa500708f00> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 0; 414 1560.67); ]
```

---

**EDIT: Debugging:**

I just tested using `collectionView.reloadData()` without changing the size of the view. This caused the same problem, the collectionview is cleared. So it is not the fact that I'm changing in the attributes that is causing the problem.

---

**EDIT 2: More debugging:**

I tried using `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` instead og `reloadData()`. This time I could see that the the new size of the cell changes properly. But when i call `reloadData()` afterwards, I get the same problem. is makes me more confident that it is `reloadData()` that causes the problem.

Comment: did you get any more insight on this?

Comment: I'm also curious if there is some progress on this one?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked into this since about the time i wrote the question..

Comment: No problems, I actually managed to solve issue few hours later. For info, if someone needs it, I had problem with layout calculation where I had wrongly calculated positions for cells in custom flow layout.

Comment: Similar sounding problem with (50%) overlapping cells. `reloadData()` on the collectionView seems to cause the cells to change position in the heirarchy. IOW, where cell 2 was on top of cell 1, after call, it is always under 1.